# Send only one $_GET input value and not all

Tags: html, forms

I have a HTML page with about 10 inputs.

There are two forms, one inside the second. I want check first the small form before sending the big one, but when I check the submit button, it refresh the page with all inputs.

How can I discriminate all inputs except  one I'm interested to?

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form id="big" name="big">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value= "" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" value= "" />
    <input type="text" name="input3" value= "" />
    <input type="text" name="input4" value= "" />


     <form id="small" name="small"><input type="text" name="sendonlythisinput" value="" />
     <inputtype="submit" value="Send only this" />
     </form>

    <buton type="submit" value="SEND ALL!" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You cannot do this without JavaScript. Also, what's the problem with sending all inputs and then only using the value from the "selected" input?

Comment: `"There are two forms, one inside the second."` - Then you have invalid HTML.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms  With invalid markup, expect the behavior to be undefined and browser-specific.

Comment: Oh, that's true. May be I try import the second from trhu a function

Comment: @ThiefMaster I make a simple check with conditions, if the $_GET vars exist all time, it's difficult to take specific control, for that reason I just want one $_GET depending the button pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom function for your button :

```
   <button type="button"   onclick="submit_custom();">submit</button>   



<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    function submit_custom(){

//do things here
and then send data via ajax or something 

    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is the best option to deal with it, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have used one form in inside the another `<form>` s in your html. You can split like below and use,

Form1:

```
    <form id="big" name="big">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value= "" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" value= "" />
    <input type="text" name="input3" value= "" />
    <input type="text" name="input4" value= "" />    

    <input type="submit" value="SEND ALL!" />
    </form>
```

Form 2:

```
     <form id="small" name="small"><input type="text" name="sendonlythisinput" value="" />
     <input type="submit" value="Send only this" />
     </form>
```

Comment: There is no problem if the form were in different places of the website, unfortunately I can't split them